# Create Sketch effect to photos using Brad Larson GPUImage in Obj C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gpuimage, imagefilter

Hi I would like to try sketch effect on photos using Brad Larson's `GPUImage` sdk in `iOS`. I am trying to create sketch effect like this

[image]

But the sketch effect i get is like this

[image]

I am using GPUImageSketchFilter to create this effect, Following are the parameters I provide to achieve this effect:

```
setTexelHeight:(1.12 / 480.0)
setTexelWidth:(0.5 / 320.0)
```

Please suggest me how to achieve this effect..

Brad going by your suggestions, i have got this...

[image]

**My Objective:** I need to make the right image look like the left one.. 
Pls suggest me..!!

Comment: how did you produce the first image?

Comment: @janusfidel the first image was produced from a sketch app.

Comment: My "sketch" filter is merely Sobel edge detection with the edge strength indicated by darkness. The image you have up above is processed by a completely different means. The darker halos near edges seem to indicate the use of an unsharp mask, so that's one stage in this. It also looks like they apply a noise texture to the image. All I can say is that you should try different combinations of filters and see what gets you the closest.

Comment: Thanks @BradLarson i will try to replicate this and would let you know...

Comment: Hey @BradLarson after trying different filters i get this.. i have added the updated effect images.. Can you suggest what more can be added to make it look perfect...

Comment: @BradLarson I am using same. But how can I get processed image from filter ? It displays as UIView.

Comment: @Maulik - `-imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput` will return a UIImage from the currently processed output of a given filter in your filter chain. If you just want to display to the screen, a GPUImageView is a better choice than a standard UIImageView.

Comment: @VivekT: getting same problem. Can you please share your code to get better sketch image ? What have you done or which filters u have used to get better output ?

Comment: @Maulik: I am yet achieve the perfect sketch effect.. After the Edit part i didn't get much time to work on this.. Give a try to combine multiple sketch filters.. Would let you know if any luck!! :)

Comment: @VivekT: It will be great help if you tell me which filters have you used to achieve perfect sketch...

Comment: @vivek: Hi , I am also using Brad Larson's GPUImage sdk for sketch but I want to know perfect combination for perfect sketch .... can you just help me out?

Comment: @PavanMore Hey Pavan, i did try to achieve perfect sketch effect combo.. Can you let me know your trials on sketch so that i can help you out..?

Comment: @VivekT : Below is the link of image that I am getting by applying with sketch filter. Please check it.  http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2013-05-23_at_5.45.37_PM-jukcIHSh.png

Comment: Follow the tutorial ... on : **http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/applying-image-filters-with-gpuimage/** You will find demo/tutorial....

Comment: @VivekT,@Maulik Do you get the perfect combination of filters. I am also facing same issue.Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Theres some information regarding the problem you are facing..
Hope this helps you out.
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/103548-pencil-sketch-of-an-image-in-iphone-sdk.html

Answer (score 0):

I  have seen a better sketch effect code,but I am  not good at filter ,I can not write a custom filter for GPUImage to apply this:

```
float res = iResolution.x;
float n0 = 97.0 / res;
float n1 = 15.0 / res;
float n2 = 97.0 / res;
float n3 = 9.7 / res;
float total = n2 + ( 4.0 * n0 ) + ( 4.0 * n1 );

const vec3 div3 = vec3(1.0 / 3.0);

void main(void) {
  float offset, temp1, temp2;
    vec4 m, p0, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6, p7, p8;
    offset = n3;

    p0=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen);
    p1=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2(-offset,-offset));
    p2=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2( offset,-offset));
    p3=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2( offset, offset));
    p4=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2(-offset, offset));

    offset=n3*2.0;

    p5=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2(-offset,-offset));
    p6=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2( offset,-offset));
    p7=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2( offset, offset));
    p8=texture2D(iCamera,iScreen+vec2(-offset, offset));
    m = (p0 * n2 + (p1 + p2 + p3 + p4) * n0 + (p5 + p6 + p7 + p8) * n1) / total;

    //convert to b/w
    temp1 = dot(p0.rgb, div3);
    temp2 = dot(m.rgb, div3);

    //color dodge blend mode
    if (temp2 <= 0.0005) {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, p0.a);
    } else {
        gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3(min(temp1 / temp2, 1.0)), p0.a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me regard this to Where can i add this above code in GPUIImage